# MAVEN ERROR : "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean "

Tags: java, maven

Need your kind help here. I am trying a very simple springweb application from Eclipse, but When I try Run As->Maven clean, I am getting below error.

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean ---requires MAVEN 3.2.5.
```

MY Maven Version is: 3.8.6, however I have read in the maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0: documentation that, it supports Maven:3.2.5+

Comment: It looks like you don't use Maven 3.8.X or even higher than 3.2.5?... Try on command line first..second which version of Eclipse do you use? Do you use an up-to-date version?

Answer (score 0):

You may **indirectly** addressing a `maven-clean-plugin` different than 3.2.0.

Please inspect your dependencies tree by `mvn dependency:tree` and find out if this is your real issue.

Answer (score 0):

my case is network block when download jar when work from office network, need setup proxy

refer to this link https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

after create settings.xml in C:\Users{username}.m2 folder
then update proxy information in settings.xml

then it success